# “Szenariogestützt” – how to write it right?

Tags: adjective

Wie schreibt man *szenariogestützt* richtig? Ich würde nach der vorgeschlagenen Form schreiben, jedoch finde ich bei Google keinen Eintrag hierzu.

Kontext:

> In einer szenariogestützen Testumgebung …

Answer (score 7):

§ 36.1.1 der Rechtschreibregeln:

> [Zusammensetzungen mit einem adjektivisch gebrauchten zweiten Bestandteil werden zusammengeschrieben], wenn der erste Bestandteil mit einer Wortgruppe paraphrasierbar ist […]

Als Beispiele werden *angsterfüllt* (erfüllt durch Angst) und *millieubedingt* (bedingt durch das Millieu) genannt. *Szenariogestützt* ist paraphrasierbar als *gestützt durch Szenarien/ein Szenario* und muss also zusammen- (und klein-) geschrieben werden.

Wenn man unbedingt möchte, könnte man noch *Szenario-gestützt* mit § 45 rechtfertigen, wonach Zusammensetzungen zur Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile oder wenn sie unübersichtlich sind, mit Bindestrich geschrieben werden dürfen. Ich würde davon aber abraten, da m. E. die Großschreibung eines Adjektivs der Lesbarkeit mehr schadet, als ihr die Kennzeichnung der Fuge hilft.